# Home button or recent won't work

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I have a Blu vivo XL and I just upgraded to 6.0 and now my home button and my recent apps button won't. The only thing that works is the back button they were working before. I don't have a clue could  have messed up during the download not sure or could it be something that doesn't require resetting the whole phone

Comment: Since you performed upgrade it's probably it's fault. Try clearing cache and dalvik, if that doesn't help than you'll have to perform factory reset. Factory reset is in most cases necessary when upgrading phone from one version to next one.